# SQL query for displaying related values on same column as separate columns

Tags: sql, sqlite, join

I have a table structure similar to this in an SQLITE database, with the LANID being a FK to another table:

```
ID   LANID    TEXT
-------------------------
1     101     Issue1
1     102     Comment1 for Issue1 
2     101     Issue2 
2     102     Comment1 for Issue2
3     101     Issue3
3     102     Comment1 for Issue3
1     102     Comment2 for Issue1
...
```

I am trying to fetch values from the TEXT field that share the same ID, using queries like this:

```
SELECT t.TEXT as issue, s.TEXT as comment
FROM MyTable as t, MyTable as s 
WHERE t.LANID = '101' and s.LANID = '102' AND t.ID = s.ID 
      AND t.TEXT like "%some text in Issue1%"
```

and it almost works, but with one problem: it can't "duplicate" values when needed. In other words, I can't display the second comment for the same issue like this:

```
issue               comment
---------------------------------
Issue1        Comment1 for Issue1
Issue1        Comment2 for Issue1 
...
```

Thanks in advance for any hints.

Comment: works http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/cdd38/6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use an explicit self `join`, instead of the implicit `join` used in your original query:

```
SELECT
  mt1.Text AS Issues,
  mt2.Text AS Comment
FROM MyTable mt1
JOIN Mytable mt2
  ON mt1.ID = mt2.ID
  AND mt1.LANID = 101
  AND mt2.LANID = 102
```

[See it in action with Sql Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/effc2/3).

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is really about how you've set up your database. Comments should be in a seperate table referencing the issues with a foreign key. Without a sound database design, you'll always be struggling with kind of thing.

Comment: Indeed, this simplified example of the real database seems to break every normalization rule, but still it is meant to handle some special cases.

Answer (score 0):

Your query **does** show the second comment.  See [this example at SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/d9c1c/2/0).

For a better way to write a `join`, see [Michael Fredrickson's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15625278/50552).

Comment: Indeed my original query works. A broken field definition on the ID was the problem and, honestly, I would have spent all night until I figured it out...Thank you.